# Update textview and progressbar in listview in Xamarin

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, progress-bar

This is my first app in Xamarin. Main menu:
[image: Main menu]

When I click on first or second button, item will be added to listview. Third button open listview:[image: Listview]

My adapter:

```
public class DownloadsAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
    {
        private List<string> items = new List<string>();
        private Activity context;

        public DownloadsAdapter(Activity context, List<string> items) : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }

        public override string this[int position]
        {
            get { return items[position]; }
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null)
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DownloadsCell, null);
            var name = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.NameInList);
            var status = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.StatusInList);
            var pbar = view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.ProgressBarInList);
            name.Text = items[position];
            //status.Text = itemsStatus[position];
            return view;
        }
    }
```

My main activity:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    List<string> downloads = new List<string>();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button loadHashcode = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.LoadHashcode);
        Button loadHashcode2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.LoadHashcode2);
        Button downloadsScreen = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.DownloadsScreen);

        loadHashcode.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            downloads.Add("firstItem");
        };

        loadHashcode2.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            downloads.Add("secondItem");
        };

        downloadsScreen.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Downloads));
            intent.PutStringArrayListExtra("downloads", downloads);
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
    }
}
```

My download activity:

```
public class Downloads : Activity
{
    Dictionary<string, Accounts> accountsList = new Dictionary<string, Accounts>();
    Dictionary<string, Task> zadania = new Dictionary<string, Task>();
    List<string> listaNazwZadan = new List<string>();
    DownloadsAdapter adapter;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //commented code for getting accountsList from server
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).SetMessage("Getting file completed").Show();

        IList<string> listWithDownloads = Intent.Extras.GetStringArrayList("downloads") ?? new string[0];
        foreach (var download in listWithDownloads)
        {
            //commented code for getting zadanie
            zadania.Add(zadanie.Name, zadanie);
            listaNazwZadan.Add(zadanie.Name);
        }

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.DownloadsLayout);
        ListView lv = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListWithTasks);
        adapter = new DownloadsAdapter(this, listaNazwZadan);
        lv.Adapter = adapter;

        lv.ItemLongClick += LvItemLongClick;
    }

    private void LvItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Task zzadanie = new Task();
        zzadanie = zadania.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == listaNazwZadan[e.Position]).Value;
        MakeDownload(zzadanie.Name);
    }

    private void MakeDownload(string nazwa)
    {
        Task zzadanie = new Task();
        zzadanie = zadania.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == nazwa).Value;
        //commented code for getting account

        //here I want set "Small Text" for clicked item to "Connecting" and progressbar to 33%
        client.Connect(account.ImapHost, account.ImapPort, (account.ImapSsl == true) ? SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect : SecureSocketOptions.None);
        //here I want set "Small Text" for clicked item to "Login" and progressbar to 66%
        client.Authenticate(zzadanie.Receivers.Keys.ElementAt(0), zzadanie.Receivers.Values.ElementAt(0));
        //here I want set "Small Text" for clicked item to "Done" and progressbar to 100%
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
}
```

I have two problems:

- I want to update textview and progressbar (commented code in `MakeDownload` function).
- When I press third button, next I back to main menu and next I press third button again, I'm getting alert "Getting file completed" again. Downloading `accountsList` from server lasts a long time and I want to download it once and use to close application.

Thanks in advance for help :)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to update textview and progressbar (commented code in MakeDownload function).

You can find the view in the `AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs` of the `ItemLongClick` event, and then find the control in this view and pass them as parameters to your `MakeDownload` method, so can you deal with them in the `MakeDownload` method, for example:

```
private void LvItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
{
    var view = e.View;
    var tv = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.StatusInList);
    var pbar = view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.ProgressBarInList);
    //Your work
    MakeDownload("abc", tv, pbar);
}

private void MakeDownload(string nazwa, TextView tv, ProgressBar pbar)
{
    //Your work
    tv.Text = nazwa;
    pbar.Progress = 60;
}
```

> When I press third button, next I back to main menu and next I press third button again, I'm getting alert "Getting file completed" again.

Sounds like that your toast is sending whenever it navigate from your `Downloads` activity back to your `MainActivity`, I'm not clear about your layout design, but in my personal opinion, this toast should be a global one. So when your file is got downloaded, your service sends a notification to your app, and when your app receive this, show this toast no matter which activity is presented at that time.

If it's not a notification from your service, you just want this toast to be shown once, you can set a bool type flag for this toast, when you want to show this toast, see if this flag is false. If it was never shown up, the flag remain to be false, and once it is shown, make the flag to true.

> Downloading accountsList from server lasts a long time and I want to download it once and use to close application.

I don't quiet understand this, you want to download only when your app is closed?If you want your file to conduct the download in the background, you may check the [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).

Comment: @grace-feng-msft Thanks for answer. Updating textview and progressbar works perfect. _I don't quiet understand this, you want to download only when your app is closed?_ **Generally:** Let's say I have item with progress eg. 50%. When I'm coming back from screen with list to main menu in my app and next I'm pressing third button again, progressbar and status "resets";  also function for getting accountsList from server is called again. This is my problem - how to call "Downloads" activity once? I hope I explained this clearly :)

Comment: Should I use bound services here?

Comment: @DamianOS.MP5, is the download state accessible by your side? If so, when you open your downloads page and when you want to add download file to the list, check the download state first.